# Replace String to html content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-html

I have this string renders from JSON "I am $1$ frontend developer works at $2$ from $3$".

Now, I want to replace `$1$,$2$` and `$3$` with dynamic html input text boxes.So, output should be I am

`<-input textbox here> frontend developer works at <-input textbox here> from <-input textbox here>.`

```
var str = "I am $1$ frontend developer works at $2$ from $3$";
var newStr = "";
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
var id = '$'+i+'$';
if (str.indexOf(id) >= 0){
   newStr = str.replace(id, $.parseHTML('<div><input type="text" 
id="input-"+i/></div>'));
}
```

I tried to use string replace method.but seems it will work only for strings.Any other methods can I use to achieve this using javascript/jquery

Comment: can you post your code whatever you have tried.

Comment: Can you show, What's your attempt?

Comment: If what you want is to replace those $number$ by a checkbox try this `"I am $1$ frontend developer works at $2$ from $3$".replace(/\$\d\$/g, '<input type=checkbox />')`

Comment: this replaces them and adds `id` value too https://jsfiddle.net/yao5zmgk/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="div1">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
var data = "I am $1$ frontend developer works at $2$ from $3$";
     //include jQuery before this code
      $(function(){
        data.replace('$1$','<input type="text" />').replace('$2$','<input type="text" />').replace('$3$','<input type="text" />');
       });

   $('#div1').html(data);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "I am $1$ frontend developer works at $2$ from $3$";
var result = input.replace(/\$\d\$/g, '<div><input type="text" id="input-"+i/></div>');
```

The result is now:

```
I am <div><input type="text" id="input-"+i/></div> frontend developer works at <div><input type="text" id="input-"+i/></div> from <div><input type="text" id="input-"+i/></div>
```

The regular expression I used is from the comment posted by @n0m4d

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
var input = "I am $1$ frontend developer works at $2$ from $3$";
var result = replaceWithInputTags(input, '$')

function replaceWithInputTags(source, templateChar){
   var sourceArgs = source.split(templateChar);

   return sourceArgs.map(function(item){
       var index = +item;
       if (isNaN(index)) return item;
       return "<input type='text' id='input-" + (index-1) + "' />";       
   }).join('');
}
```